# DataGridViewColumnSortMode is set to NotSortable, but some columns still get sorted

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

A have a `DataGridView` with 6 columns, all of them is set to `SortMode.NotSortable`, but 2 columns still can be sorted, they have the little arrow glyph as well.
I set the `SortMode` right after creating the columns. Do you have any ideas what might be the problem?

Here is my code:

```
dataGridView1.Columns.Add("dgvColumn1", "First Column");
dataGridView1.Columns["dgvColumn1"].SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;
```

I do it like this with all columns. This happens every time when the form loads, because I add row data to the DataGridView from selected listBox items, so it's always changing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried applying this `SortMode.NotSortable` to every column?

I can see you did not post your code here... So I can only help you out blindly considering some scenarios. If still have any problem, I will suggest- Please post your code

You can Either do this using this code

```
foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView.Columns 
       {                                              
         column.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;  
        }
```

or You can do it like this

> right click on datagridview --> click on edit columns --> set SortMode to NotSortable